# jQuery draggable for live events on iPad

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I am trying to drag live divs returned from ajax. the following code works nice for desktop, but on iPad, I have to drag (on page load) each of the draggable twice, once to initialize and then to drag. Any help in making this one drag even on page load? My code is as the following:

html:

```
<div class="draggable"> drag this </div>
```

jQuery:

```
$.fn.liveDraggable = function (opts) 
    { 
        
        if((navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)) || (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i)) || (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i))) 
        {
              this.live("touchstart", function() {
                 if (!$(this).data("init")) {
                    $(this).data("init", true).draggable(opts);
                 }
              });
              return $();
        }
        else
        {
             this.live("mouseover", function() {
                 if (!$(this).data("init")) {
                    $(this).data("init", true).draggable(opts);
                 }
              });
              
              return $();
        }
        
    };
                
$(".draggable").liveDraggable(
    {  
        helper: 'clone',            
        containment: '#origin'
        
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't bind mouseover events and expect them to have a 1 to 1 relationship on touch devices. Simply put I have the same issue and have not found a solution besides not using a live model which kind of sucks, as you have to re-initialise everything everytime you add a new dom element meant to inherit those properties.

On a side note.

try the following for determine if you have already attached a live event to that element.

```
if (!$(this).data("draggable")) {
   $(this).draggable(opts);
}
```

Basically you are negating the need of adding random data() attributes like

```
'.data("init", true)'
```

The above prevents cluttering that name space with something you don't need, since draggable once attached is always true, and draggable methods can be removed quite easily.